# How do I enable downloading using X-sendfile in rails3 from a directory other than the public directory?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, apache2, ubuntu-10.04

I have enabled the XSendFile module in Apache 2 running on Ubuntu 10.04.  I have added the `XSendFile on` directive and restarted the Apache server successfully.  When I add the `XSendFilePath /path/to/dir` directive and restart Apache I get the following error:

*Invalid command 'XSendFilePath', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration*

Not sure what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 7):

On 10.04 Lucid, the version of XSendFile installed by apt by default is 0.9.2:

http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/libapache2-mod-xsendfile

The directive XSendFilePath replaced XSendFileAllowAbove in version 0.1.0, so for 0.9.2:

https://tn123.org/mod_xsendfile/

Try using XSendFileAllowAbove if you're on anything less than 0.1.0

Answer (score 3):

Do you have the x-sendfile module installed and enabled in apache? Run "apachectl -M" to see a list of all of modules. You may have to build it, see https://tn123.org/mod_xsendfile/